# Google OAUTH is not storing email in the MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I can console.log the complete profile when a user registers via Google-OAUTH2.0, but how can I save that whole console.log output in my userDB mongoDB? If not then how can I get the email of the user in my database?

```
app.use(session({
  secret: "process.env.SECRET",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
```

I just get googleId or facebookId, but i want email and displayName as well.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  email: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  displayName: String
}, {
  versionKey: false

});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/myaccount"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
     console.log(accessToken);
     console.log(refreshToken);
     console.log(profile);

    User.findOrCreate({googleId: profile.id}, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/myaccount",
    passReqToCallback : true,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name'] //This
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(accessToken);
    console.log(refreshToken);
    console.log(profile);

    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

  app.get('/auth/google/myaccount',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/signin' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/myaccount');
  });

  app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'), { scope : ['email'] });

app.get('/auth/facebook/myaccount',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/signin' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/myaccount');
  })
```

Also for facebook how can I get email and then save it in my MongoDB.

Comment: can you add your code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in Google Strategy:

```
 passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/myaccount"
      passReqToCallback   : true
    },
    (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOrCreate({ username: profile.email }, (err, user) => {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
    ));
```